# Find a bisecting Diameter

Tags: computational-geometry

Given n points on a circle, we have to find a diameter such that the number of points on each side of the diameter is equal. Now, this can be solved in linear time if the points are sorted. How about when they are not sorted. Can we still achieve linear time?

Comment: Is `n` guaranteed to be even? If not, then one of the diameter endpoints needs to coincide with one of the points...

Comment: It seems like [selection/median](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm) problem, since points can be represent as angles and split diameter is an angle (da) which satisfies that half of points are in interval [da, da+pi]. Maybe you can add tags like algorithm or sorting.

Comment: It does not matter if n is even or odd.